# Group by in JPA criteria query

Tags: mysql, jpa, criteria

I have a table like it:

```
  id  |  value  |  name
------+---------+--------
  1   |    a    | name1  
  2   |    b    | name2  
  3   |    a    | name3  
  4   |    a    | name4  
  5   |    c    | name5 
  6   |    b    | name6  
  7   |    c    | name7  
  8   |    b    | name8
```

and what I want is:

```
  id  |  value  |  names
------+---------+---------------------------
  1   |    a    | name1 , name3, name4
  2   |    b    | name2 , name6, name8
  3   |    c    | name5 , name7
```

In fact I want to get all records in each group and iterate on these records.
I tried this code, but it does not works:

```
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
Root<T> c = cq.from(entityClass);

cq.select(c);

cq.groupBy(c.get("value"));
javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
return q.getResultList();
```

thanks.

Comment: Such a list could better be displayed after getting the desired rows from the database. It is very unlikely to have a direct query (not sure though).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK query which you want to do is not possible even with SQL Standard.

It would be possible with aggregating functions depended on database vendor.

Since it is not possible with SQL Standard for sure it's not possible with JPQL.

Here are aggregate functions which are supported by JPQL: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_aggregates

I'm pretty sure you have to do conversion on your own or create view with data you need and then query view

PS. code which you're presenting implies that you don't understand what query will be generated by JPA. I suggest you to try write query in MySQL and then convert it to JPQL.